# I need help to split a cell into two columns

Tags: html, html-table

Just like how in the image I linked "tache1" and "tache2" in the 4th row are splitting "Mercredi" in two

[image: Goal]

```html
<table width="400" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <th width="15%" rowspan="2">Equipes</th>
    <th width="70%" colspan="5">Janvier</th>
    <td width="15%" rowspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Lundi</th>
    <th>Mardi</th>
    <th>Mercredi</th>
    <th>Jeudi</th>
    <th>Vendredi</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Equipe1</td>
    <td colspan="3">tache1</td>
    <td colspan="2">tache2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Semaine1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">tache1</td>
    <td colspan="3">tache2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also try to use valid HTML. Missing `</table>` and `<thead></thead><tbody></tbody>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 6 colspan instead of 5 in `<th width="70%" colspan="6">Janvier</th>` **Then** use 2 colspan for `Mercredi` like this `<th colspan="2">Mercredi</th>` **Then** use 3 colspan for each `tache` like this

```
 <td colspan="3">tache1</td>
 <td colspan="3">tache2</td>
```

Also In your setup, Equip1 is taking 2 rows but its content to the right take only 1 row.

so use rowspan"1" for both Equipe1 and 2.

```html
<table width="600" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
      <th width="15%" rowspan="2">Equipes</th>
      <th width="70%" colspan="6">Janvier</th>
      <td width="15%" rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Lundi</th>
      <th>Mardi</th>
      <th colspan="2">Mercredi</th>
      <th>Jeudi</th>
      <th>Vendredi</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">Equipe1</td>
      <td colspan="3">tache1</td>
      <td colspan="3">tache2</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Semaine1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">Equipe2</td>
      <td colspan="3">tache1</td>
      <td colspan="3">tache2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Well you're not wrong, but I'm afraid that doesn't answer the question at all...

Comment: @StephanBauer lol true, I think I got the wrong idea by mistake. Aleight, let me try to answer the question now.

Comment: @StephanBauer thanks for the note, I think I got it right this time. :)

Comment: @Willpower-7 thank you for helping me solve this problem, but now that I have the column split in two I can't quite do exactly the table in the picture in my post earlier.

Comment: the "tach1" in the 3rd row is in 3 columns but the "tache1" in the 4th row is in 2 and a halt columns. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @OTMANDIE so what do you want to happen? do you want to center the text or what?

Comment: Not really just like how i said the 3rd and 4th row r not the same in the image unlike the code u suggested to me